# docker attach with colored log output and without stop container?

Tags: docker

faced with issue : when i am trying to run container :

```
docker run -t -p 3000:3000 --name container-dev-local image-dev-local
```

i am getting pretty much colored output with my logs :

[image]

But :

1. how can i exit without stopping container? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> don't work, it exiting and stop container

Update:
found the way to start without attaching by adding -d param :

```
docker run -d -p //other params
```

so now, after run - it starts in detached state, but **colored logs dissapearing** when i tried to attach

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false container-dev-local
```

[image]

But after attaching i still **can't exit from it without stopping process**, CTRL+C, CTRL+P+Q does not work - it suspending process.
And how can i return back colorized logs? Have no ideas

My pre-requisites are : Windows 10, .net core inside of .nix container, visual studio 2019 and powershell terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

First, you need to apply to docker run "-dti" flag, it enabling tty + detached mode (see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/))
It allows you to run container and trying to attach to it by

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false container-dev-local
```

So now, **you should see colored logs** as `-ti` is also applied during run command.

**How to exit without termination?**

First, you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> should be pressed in time of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) command. It will stop your outer task and your terminal will ask you "Stop job?(y/n)" - then type "n" and ... should work :) You will be detached, container will continue work.

Second, we can override "detached keys" by adding `--detach-keys` :

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false --detach-keys="ctrl-c" container-dev-local
```

And then, just try to simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the same result will be achieved.

About CTRL+Z you can get some info here : [What's different between Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C in Unix command line](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line)